# py_script writing xlsx file from mysql bd

Tags: python, mysql

I am currently running this script to write an xlsx file from mysql. However, my column comes back as 0.
Am I using the wrong call

## > for c, col in enumerate(row):

## See complete script below:

```
import MySQLdb
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

user = '' # your username
passwd = '' # your password
host = '' # your host
db = '' # database where your table is stored
table = '' # table you want to save

con = MySQLdb.connect(user=user, passwd=passwd, host=host, db=db)
cursor = con.cursor()

query = "SELECT * FROM %s;" % table
cursor.execute(query)

workbook = Workbook('outfile.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
for r, row in enumerate(cursor.fetchall()):
for c, col in enumerate(row):
    sheet.write(r, c, col)
```

I expect the the columns to come back at value, however they come back at zero.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is not indented properly. The second `for` loop is not inside the first `for` loop. Try this:

```
for r, row in enumerate(cursor.fetchall()):
    for c, col in enumerate(row):
        sheet.write(r, c, col)
```

Also, if you are writing a lot of data without any special cell specific formatting, you should consider using Pandas.

Source: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html